# Include a class within itself under a class function in C++

Tags: c++

This code compiles fine and outputs 10, but i'm not sure why?

```
#include <iostream>

class test1 {
  public:
  int getId(){
     test1 t;
     return t.getAnotherId();
  }
  int getAnotherId(){
     return 10;
  }
};

int main(){
   test1 t;
   std::cout << t.getId() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Is `test1` fully defined yet when it's being called under `getId()`?

I am asking because I know this is not valid since class isn't fully defined yet:

```
class Node {
    char *cargo;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return this->getAnotherId();` in `int getId()`? Your class is complete, but `10` never changes.

Comment: because i'm testing the reason behind how it's working like this, i'm creating a class within itself.

Comment: Well, your class is complete, hard to tell what you are doing, but your original `class test1` serves as a forward-declaration making `test1 t;` OK.

Answer (score 3):

From 9.2.2 of the spec:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-
>   specifier. Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
>   default arguments, using-declarations introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), exception-specifications, and
>   brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise
>   it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

So within the body of the method, the class is complete and can be used as a complete type (so you can define a local of the class type).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two different things.

```
class Node {
    char *cargo;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

The above will not work because you will quickly fill available memory once you create one of those. This is because each object will create (more like attempt to create) two copies of itself til infinitum.

The way this is done in Cpp is to use either use `std::optional` or use a pointer.

```
class Node {
    char *cargo = nullptr;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;
};
```

with `std::optional`, you do:

```
class Node {
  char *cargo = nullptr
  std::optional<Node> left = std::nullopt;
  std::optional<Node> right = std::nullopt;
};
```

---

```
int getId(){
  test1 t;
  return t.getAnotherId();
}
```

In this case, `t1` is a variable and not part of the class fields, so it is ok to create an instance of it inside the method body.

Answer (score 0):

To make things clearer let's change your code a bit

```
#include <iostream>

class test1 {
  public:
  int getId(){
     test1 t1; // I change this t to t1
     return t1.getAnotherId();
  }
  int getAnotherId(){
     return 10;
  }
};

int main(){
   test1 t2; // I change this t to t2
   std::cout << t2.getId() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Your `test1` class is defined, but this class only has methods in it which is `getId()` and `getAnotherId()` but doesn't have any attribute. This is what a class looks like.

```
class CLASS_NAME {
   DATA_TYPE VARIABLE_NAME1
   DATA_TYPE VARIABLE_NAME2
   DATA_TYPE VARIABLE_NAME3
   // and so on...

   RETURN_TYPE METHOD_NAME1(params) {
      // some code here...
   }
   RETURN_TYPE METHOD_NAME2(params) {
      // some code here...
   }
   // and so on...
}
```

In the `main` section you're making an object for `test1` class called `t2`. Then you're calling `getId()` method, and this method makes another object for `test1` class called `t1`. `getId()` method then returns a value which you set as `t1.getAnotherId()` which is `10`, because `getAnotherId()` method is returning a value of `10`.

In the simplest way, your code is only doing this:

```
#include <iostream>

class test1 {
  public:
  int getId(){
     return 10;
  }
};

int main(){
   test1 t2; // I change this t to t2
   std::cout << t2.getId() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

---